# C++ std::unique_ptr but non movable?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm using std::unique_ptr to create some public members on a class and those members must be non copyable or movable. But std::unique_ptr is movable and I was wondering what would happen if someone would move the pointer contained by an std::unique_ptr and then I try to access the std::unique_ptr member of that class that was moved.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct obj
{
    obj(std::string id)
        : id(id)
    {

    }

    void identif()
    {
        std::cout << "i am " << id << std::endl;
    }

    std::string id;
};

struct objs
{
    // They must stay here no mater what.
    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_a;
    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_b;
    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_c;

    objs()
        : obj_a(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object a") ))
            ,obj_b(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object b") ))
            ,obj_c(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object c") ))
    {

    }

    void do_a()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_a->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_a->identif();
    }

    void do_b()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_b->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_b->identif();
    }

    void do_c()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_c->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_c->identif();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    objs obx;

    std::cout << " before move: " << std::endl;

    obx.do_a();
    obx.do_b();
    obx.do_c();

    std::cout << " after move: " << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr< obj > newb(std::move(obx.obj_b));

    obx.do_a();
    obx.do_b();
    obx.do_c();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The application crashes because of course which leads me to my question. How can I protect against that?

The objects must be public, not constant and unable to move or copy. The actual object in question uses variadic templates and I would prefer to not use the old way with a static member function create() in obj and then protect the constructors.
Also I need to avoid geters and setters since the class uses variadic templates and makes the code ugly as hell.

All I need is to make std::unique_ptr non movable and to simply hold a unique pointer that can't be moved or copied ever from the class that owns it.

The actual code in question is the Nano::signal class from the [Nano-signal-slot](http://code.google.com/p/nano-signal-slot/) library. (*in case someone needs the actual code*)

EDIT:
Adapted to use Nevin's method and made it to work. I've posted the code because Nevin implements it on the container and not the objects.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct obj
{
    obj(std::string id)
        : id(id)
    {

    }

    obj(obj const&) = delete;
    obj& operator=(obj const&) = delete;
    obj& operator=(obj&&) = delete;
    obj(obj&&) = delete;


    void identif()
    {
        std::cout << "i am " << id << std::endl;
    }

    std::string id;
};

struct objs
{
    const std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_a;
    const std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_b;
    const std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_c;

    objs()
        : obj_a(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object a") ))
            ,obj_b(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object b") ))
            ,obj_c(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object c") ))
    {

    }

    void do_a()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_a->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_a->identif();
    }

    void do_b()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_b->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_b->identif();
    }

    void do_c()
    {
        std::cout << " member: " << obj_c->id << std::endl;
        std::cout << " method: ";
        obj_c->identif();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    objs obx;

    std::cout << " before move: " << std::endl;

    obx.do_a();
    obx.do_b();
    obx.do_c();

    std::cout << " after move: " << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr< obj > newb(std::move(obx.obj_b));

    obx.do_a();
    obx.do_b();
    obx.do_c();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This should now generate:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:77:53: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = obj; _Dp = std::default_delete<obj>]'
     std::unique_ptr< obj > newb(std::move(obx.obj_b));
                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^
```

Comment: Why can't you make them `const`?

Comment: Hmm this actually works. I thought that making std::unique_ptr const would also make obj const and obj won't be able to modify it's members though methods. Sucks to be a noob like me :) Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want people mucking around with your data members, why are you leaving them `public`?  The whole purpose of encapsulation is to prevent this type of thing from happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make `objs` non-copyable and non-moveable, as in:

```
struct objs
{
    objs(objs const&) = delete;
    objs& operator=(objs const&) = delete;
    objs& operator=(objs&&) = delete;
    objs(objs&&) = delete;

    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_a;
    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_b;
    std::unique_ptr< obj > obj_c;

    objs()
        : obj_a(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object a") ))
            ,obj_b(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object b") ))
            ,obj_c(std::unique_ptr< obj >( new obj("object c") ))
        {}

};
```

Plus, once you've done that, there is no need for pointers internally either.  You can simplify the code as:

```
struct objs
{
    objs(objs const&) = delete;
    objs& operator=(objs const&) = delete;
    objs& operator=(objs&&) = delete;
    objs(objs&&) = delete;

    obj obj_a;
    obj obj_b;
    obj obj_c;

    objs()
        : obj_a("object a")
            ,obj_b("object b")
            ,obj_c("object c")
            {}

};
```

Comment: It's actually the obj (the object) that must not be moved and not objs (the container). But I'm testing this now. Thank you :)

Comment: [This doesn't work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003e7a49a4598802) Making the class non-copyable/non-moveable doesn't mean its members cannot be moved.

Comment: I've translated this to the objects and it works. std::unique_ptr< obj > newb(std::move(obx.obj_b)); doesn't work. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a470a7230b37c9db

Answer (score 0):

```
newb(std::move(obx.obj_b))
```

This code is expected to leave `obx` in an unspecified state, so you should not try to access it again, rather try to access `newb`. If you don't want the contained `unique_ptr`'s to be moved, then don't move their container `obx`. Or, if you want to define the semantics of (or disable) moving struct `objs`, then provide your own move constructor (assignment, etc.) or delete the default one(s), depending on what you want to do.